# net displacement and path dependence

Tags: general-relativity

reading the paper about [spacetime swimming by Wisdom](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/wayne0/papers/belgrade/Wisdom-swimming03.pdf)
 (something related to this has been [previously asked here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/886/swimming-in-spacetime-apparent-conserved-quantity-violation)) can't help but think that there is more to this than what is on the paper.

Basically the paper just proves that inertially, an object can get a net displacement by using the fact that phases are path-dependent due to non-commutativity in space paths, and he uses the rotational argument to properly ambient his point. The punchline here is that this same argument seems to be applicable when the masses have also for instance, a magnetic dipole, and there is a geometric phase in the magnetic field due to curvature

Do you think that the same argument are applicable to obtain a similar effect due electric charges or magnetic dipoles in a curved manifold? i'm aware the question is vague but i hope this can entice (or stir) at least some deep discussion on the subject

As a side (but very important) question; is not clear from the paper if the displacement is constrained to go only down in the gravitational potential well, but most discussions and papers referencing [it says it should be so](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0510054) (check the conclusions section and comments)