# How would you move without gravity?

Tags: gravity, space, air, kinematics

I'm wondering how would you move without gravity? You would still have air pressure at 1Atm.

Would you "swim" in the air or would you have do something else?

Comment: Larry Niven speculated at length on the possibilities in *The Integral Trees* and *The Smoke Ring*. Many other source in the SF literature have had some guesses to make.

Comment: Those books are so awesome. I don't care if a lot of the characterization and dialog are really cheesy; the world is just so **cool**. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees

Comment: @Keenan: High Wow!-factor, and sometimes spotty characterization are par for the course with Niven. He *does* write really believable, human characters from time to time, but you can't count on it. I think it's the place he benefits most from collaboration.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/886/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: with great difficulty.

In a space ship there should be hand holds and footholds and a grid of ropes crisscrossing and you would move by pulling and pushing yourself: muscle power.

Air is too thin to get a reactive force to propel yourself effectively by swimming.

Once a motion is started, stopping will have to be taken into account too.

Comment: Portable jet packs would be useful.

Comment: Without gravity, you'd jut need some sort of broad cloth to catch air.  Or wings.  Birds do just fine even with the Earth's gravity.

Comment: @Jerry True,  in a large enough space, wings would work, and training how to stop will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. So you could "swim" if you had wings but hand/foot holds seems the best idea.

Comment: @Jerry why wings?  How about a portable fan...  I mean, you could be quite mobile with a fairly simple setup.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Well we could use arrangements springs and nets.

Example:
Suppose you want to get from A to B. There is spring at A (launcher spring) and there is another spring at C(deflector spring). There is a net at B to catch you. And the big black rectangle is a house.

You firmly push your head against spring at A and let go. Once you reach spring C it will deflect you and at B the net will catch you. Please wear helmet!

Answer (score 0):

I would grow long nails on my hands and feet, and then run like a beast with the nails firmly in the soil at all times :) If I accidentally leave the surface, I would huff and puff in the reverse direction until I reach the surface again.

Comment: Because Water (all of it!) would not stay in rivers/sea and soil once levitated from ground would "fly" around, we would have a lot such floating "things" around to grip and throw backwards.