# How to find distance of closest approach for a Schwarzschild geodesic?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, geodesics

What is the distance of closest approach in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Bending_of_light_by_gravity)?

I can't seem to find its definition, and [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52824) doesn't have an answer I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

The Schwarzschild spacetime has Killing vector fields $\partial_t$ and $\partial_\phi$ that give conservation of specific energy and angular momentum, respectively:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}e = \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\text{,} &\quad\quad& l= r^2\sin^2\theta\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\text{,}\end{eqnarray*}$$
although one can also obtain those constants of motion by integrating the components of geodesic equation directly. Here $\lambda$ is any affine parameter for the geodesic, which for timelike ones can be taken to be the proper time.

The parameter $b$ is simply the ratio $b = \left|l/e\right|$.

It is commonly called the *[impact parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_parameter)* for the following reason. For $r\gg 2M$, spacetime is approximately Minkowski. Let the light ray be in the equatorial plane ($\theta = \pi/2$) and take Cartesian axes such that the light ray is parallel to one of them at infinity with $d$ the distance from the ray to that axis,
$$b \approx \frac{r^2\mathrm{d}\phi/\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\lambda} = r^2\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t} = r^2\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{dr}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t} \approx d\text{,}$$
where we approximated $\phi \approx d/r$ and $\mathrm{d}r/\mathrm{d}t \approx -1$ in the distant limit.